# Can you compile a library with your src's into a new library?

Tags: c, makefile, compilation, static-libraries

I am trying to compile a new library using ranlib with .a and *.c/$(SRCS) in a Makefile in C. Is this possible?

Adding a .a somewhere in here?

```
    gcc -g -c $(SRC)
    ar rc $(LIB) *.o
    ranlib $(LIB)
```

Comment: Recommend formatting your code.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your question.

Comment: If the question is "can make be used to build the .o files, archive them into a .a file, and then run ranlib, the answer is yes.  In fact you can put all three steps into a single rule.  Each step begins with a tab, and occurs on successive lines under the "target : deps" line

Comment: What I was trying to ask is, can I compile a (.a)library with all the .o files into a new (.a)library. Ex: gcc -g -c *.c lib.a; ar rc $(LIB) *.o;  ranlib newlib.a;

Comment: This is how I did it:

 gcc -g -c *.c;
 ar rcs lib.a *.o;
 ar -x other_lib.a; 
 ar -x lib.a;
 ar rcs new_lib.a *.o;   //extracts .o files from the lib